# Checkboxes are not aligned

Tags: html, css

I was able to align the second checkbox but not the first one. I have used the .Checkbox CSS is shown below and it is working for the second box. Do not know why it is not working for the first checbkbox.

```css
label {
    background-color: white;
    width: 130px; 
    clear: left;
    text-align: left;/*change this R to L*/
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 4px;
  }

  input,
  label {
    float: left;
  }

  .Checkbox{
    clear:none;
    text-align: right;
     white-space: nowrap;

}
```

```html
<div class="sc-formfield-input">
   <label class="Checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="Attendance" data-field-type="Text" value="Will Attend In Person" required="required" data-validation-message="Please fill out this field.">&nbsp;Will Attend In Person</label></div>
  <br>

<div class="sc-formfield-input">
  <label class="Checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="Attendance" data-field-type="Text" value="Will Attend Virtually" required="required" data-validation-message="Please fill out this field.">&nbsp;Will Attend Virtually
  </label>
</div>
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/soyvtp41/)**

[image: View issue]

Comment: Can you provide a .js fiddle so that we can see your code in action?

Comment: This looks to be aligned to me? Or do you need them side by side? Please be more specific in your question

Comment: I posted the screenshot not sure you guys see it .

Comment: @calo, there is no screenshot. Can you specify if you are looking for aligning it side by side or one after another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change clear style.

```
clear: both;
```

Does this help you?

Comment: Thanks! This is it. I also had to use padding-right: 20px;
 padding-left: 72px;

Answer (score 2):

`float` was causing some issues. Check the below snippet with updated HTML/CSS

```css
label {
  background-color: white;
  width: 130px;
  clear: left;
  text-align: left; /*change this R to L*/
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 4px;
}

.Checkbox {
  clear: none;
  text-align: right;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
  <div class="sc-formfield-input">
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      name="Attendance"
      data-field-type="Text"
      value="Will Attend In Person"
      required="required"
      data-validation-message="Please fill out this field."
    />
    <label class="Checkbox">&nbsp;Will Attend In Person</label>
  </div>
  <div class="sc-formfield-input">
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      name="Attendance"
      data-field-type="Text"
      value="Will Attend Virtually"
      required="required"
      data-validation-message="Please fill out this field."
    />
    <label class="Checkbox">&nbsp;Will Attend Virtually</label>
  </div>
```